# Где можно прочитать про WinApi функции?

Tags: winapi

Попытался посмотреть тут, но тут я не нашел ОС выше Win 7
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383687

Неужели после Win 7 Api  не обновлялось?

Comment: https://www.rsdn.ru , https://www.msdn.microsoft.com , http://www.vsokovikov.narod.ru/New_MSDN_API/ , сайтов много, Гугл в помощь

Comment: Учитывая, что его сейчас можно спокойно изучить по книге Петцольда 97 года, в WinApi почти ничего не поменялось.

Comment: "Неужели после Win 7 Api не обновлялось?" -- хорошая проверка на прочность интерфейса, хорошо, что не поменялось.